# Is it useful to replace old styled linux shell command with well designed?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, powershell

I found out that linux commands are too old and require a lot of effort in order to learn all of them.

Is it reasonable to replace them with new ones?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're talking about.  Do you mean rewriting some specific commands that you have in a script or something?  Or are you asking if the Linux community will change the system's whole command-line interface for you?  And what does it mean for a command to be "too old" anyway?

Comment: *"require a lot of effort in order to learn all of them"* I suppose you mean *exactly the opposite of* Powershell? What does this have to do with Windows, anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu has done its best to set GUIs in place of most of the commands.

Other than implementing GUIs, though, replacing the commands with 'new' commands will just be a lot of effort to learn all of them *and* a lot of effort to rewrite all of them, so the answer to your question is, "No."

Your best bet is not to learn all of them at once, but instead to learn a few of them for whatever you need right now, and maybe some will stick.  Then learn a few more for the next task and maybe the first few will come in handy, and so on.

Comment: You I compared your answer with another person on quora and found that your answer is not constructive. No understanding what to do. Take a look https://www.quora.com/Why-do-linux-commands-are-so-complicated

Comment: You asked a different question than the quora asker:  He asked "why?"  You asked, "Is it reasonable to replace?"  I say no, because it requires work for *everyone * to relearn and requires work for unpaid coders to code new ones.  Seems concise, and furthermore, my constructive advice about how to learn them has served me well.  If you want to change things, feel free; the project is open source by its very nature.